# Inherit HTTParty module

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming, httparty

How can I inherit HTTParty module to set some default values?

```
module SuperClient
  include HTTParty

  headers 'Auth' => 'Basic'
end

module ServiceApiClient
  include SuperClient

  headers 'X-Prop' => 'Some specific data'
  base_uri 'https://example.com'

  def self.posts
    self.get '/posts'
    # Expected to send headers Auth and X-Prop
  end
end
```

I need to have some customized module, that can be included in client classes and behave like native HTTParty module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the only intent is to set default values and not to re-define methods the following would do the trick:

```
module SuperClient
  def self.included(base)
    base.include HTTParty

    # defaults
    base.headers 'Auth' => 'Basic'
    # or
    base.class_eval do
      headers 'Auth' => 'Basic'
    end
  end
end
```

When you include `SuperClient` it will then include `HTTParty` and set some defaults. If this is the only functionality you need this is your answer if you're also planning on re-defining methods read further.

---

This does **not** work if you're planning to redefine methods. `HTTParty` will be added to the ancestor stack before `SuperClient`. When calling methods defined by both `SuperClient` and `HTTParty` the `HTTParty` variant will be called first, meaning the `SuperClient` variant will never be reached.

This might be more info than you need, but the above issue can be solved by doing:

```
module SuperClient
  def self.included(base)
    base.include HTTParty
    base.include InstanceMethods
    base.extend  ClassMethods

    # defaults
    # ...
  end

  module InstanceMethods
    # ...
  end

  module ClassMethods
    # ...
  end
end
```

By including `InstanceMethods` and extending `ClassMethods` after including `HTTParty` they will sit higher up the stack, allowing you to re-define methods and call `super`.

```
class C
  include SuperClient
end

# methods are search for from top to bottom
puts C.ancestors
# C
# SuperClient::InstanceMethods
# HTTParty::ModuleInheritableAttributes
# HTTParty
# SuperClient
# Object
# JSON::Ext::Generator::GeneratorMethods::Object
# Kernel
# BasicObject

puts C.singleton_class.ancestors
# #<Class:C>
# SuperClient::ClassMethods
# HTTParty::ModuleInheritableAttributes::ClassMethods
# HTTParty::ClassMethods
# #<Class:Object>
# #<Class:BasicObject>
# Class
# Module
# Object
# JSON::Ext::Generator::GeneratorMethods::Object
# Kernel
# BasicObject
```

Comment: My final goal is not to retreat from HTTParty's DSL both in SuperClient, neither in ServiceApiClient. And achieve it with single include statement. But I see now, that HTTParty is not designed for such manipulations.

Comment: What do you mean by *"HTTParty's DSL"*? Do you mean that in `base.headers 'Auth' => 'Basic'` you don't want the `base`? Because that can be fixed. See the updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can keep the SuperClient as a class and inherit other clients from it. Something like this. Both headers 'Auth' and 'X-Prop' will be included in the request.

```rb
require 'httparty'

class SuperClient 
    include HTTParty

    headers 'Auth' => 'Basic'
    # Uncomment below line to print logs in terminal
    # debug_output STDOUT
end

class ServiceApiClient < SuperClient

    headers 'X-Prop' => 'Some specific data'
    base_uri 'https://example.com'

    def posts
        self.class.get '/posts'
        # Expected to send headers Auth and X-Prop
  end
end         

client = ServiceApiClient.new

client.posts()
```

Comment: My ServiceApiClient should inherit from other Business class. Thats why I'm looking for modular solution.